# Jquery conditional calculator going haywire after selecting couple of items

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements, calculator

I'm currently building a calorie calculator. All is fine, but I think that my equation can't handle decimal numbers.

Here's the issue: If I select 3-5 ingredients. The calorie calculator starts giving me faulty results (.00000001 differences). I can't figure out the error in the javascript logic.

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ingredient').click(function() {
    var totalNum = $('#total');
    var totalCarbs = $('#totalCarbs');
    var totalFats = $('#totalFats');
    var totalProteins = $('#totalProteins');
    var pressed = $(this).hasClass('clicked');
    var currentCalories = +totalNum.html();
    var currentCarbs = +totalCarbs.html();
    var currentFats = +totalFats.html();
    var currentProteins = +totalProteins.html();

    if (pressed) {
      $(this).removeClass('clicked');
      var calories = $(this).data('calories');
      var carbs = $(this).data('carbs');
      var fat = $(this).data('fat'); +
      totalNum.html(currentCalories - calories); +
      totalCarbs.html(currentCarbs - carbs); +
      totalFats.html(currentFats - fat); +
      totalProteins.html(currentProteins - proteins);
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('clicked');
      var calories = $(this).data('calories');
      var carbs = $(this).data('carbs');
      var fat = $(this).data('fat');
      var proteins = $(this).data('fat'); +
      totalNum.html(currentCalories + calories); +
      totalCarbs.html(currentCarbs + carbs); +
      totalFats.html(currentFats + fat); +
      totalProteins.html(currentProteins + fat);
    }

    // vegan      
    var vegan = false;
    var vegetarian = false;
    $(".ingredient.clicked").each(function() {
      if (typeof $(this).attr("vegan") != "undefined") {
        vegan = true;
      } else {
        vegan = false;
        return false;
      }
    });

    if (vegan) {
      $('#type').text("Ez az összeállítás Vegán");
      $('#typeImage').attr("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/hi/thumb/b/b2/Veg_symbol.svg/768px-Veg_symbol.svg.png");
    } else {
      $('#type').text("");
      $('#typeImage').attr("src", "");
    }

    $(".ingredient.clicked").each(function() {
      if (typeof $(this).attr("vegetarian") != "undefined") {
        vegetarian = true;
      } else {
        vegetarian = false;
        return false;
      }
    });

    if (vegetarian) {
      $('#typeVega').text("Ez az összeállítás vegetáriánus");
      $('#typeImageVega').attr("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/hi/thumb/b/b2/Veg_symbol.svg/768px-Veg_symbol.svg.png");
    } else {
      $('#typeVega').text("");
      $('#typeImageVega').attr("src", "");
    }
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="ingredients">
    <p style="color:white; text-align:center; margin: auto auto;">Select all the ingredients you added to your padthai wokbar meal and we'll do the rest.</p>
    <br>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <h2 style="color:#6FC0BB;">BASES</h2>
        </th>
        <th>
          <h2 style="color:#C84327;">MEATS</h2>
        </th>
        <th>
          <h2 style="color:#C84327;">TOPPINGS</h2>
        </th>
        <th>
          <h2 style="color:white;">SAUCES</h2>
        </th>
        <th>
          <h2 style="color:#6FC0BB;">EXTRA TOPPINGS</h2>
        </th>
        <th>
          <h2 style="color:#90A94D;">TEAS</h2>
        </th>
        <th>
          <h2 style="color:white;">DESSERTS</h2>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="ingredient" data-calories="517.2" data-carbs="76.1" data-fat="14.4" data-proteins="20.8" vegan vegetarian>
            <p>Rice Noodles
              <p>
                <td>
                  <div class="ingredient" data-calories="65.9" data-carbs="0.2" data-fat="1.5" data-proteins="12.9">
                    <p>Chicken
                      <p>
                  </div>
                  <td>
                    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="11.3" data-carbs="1.2" data-fat="0.1" data-proteins="1.4">
                      <p>Vegetable Mix
                        <p>
                    </div>
                    <td>
                      <div class="ingredient" data-calories="15" data-carbs="2.3" data-fat="0.6" data-proteins="0.1">
                        <p>Thailand-Padthai
                          <p>
                            <td>
                              <div class="ingredient" data-calories="145.9" data-carbs="2.2" data-fat="12.3" data-proteins="6.6">
                                <p>Roasted Peanuts
                                  <p>
                                    <td>
                                      <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                                        <p>PADTEA Classic
                                          <p>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="ingredient" data-calories="510.5" data-carbs="66.1" data-fat="14.1" data-proteins="29.8" vegan vegetarian>
            <p>Egg Noodles
              <p>

                <td>
                  <div class="ingredient" data-calories="166.4" data-carbs="0.1" data-fat="14" data-proteins="10">
                    <p>Pork
                      <p>
                  </div>

                  <td>
                    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="160" data-carbs="9" data-fat="12" data-proteins="4">
                      <p>Cashew
                        <p>
                    </div>

                    <td>
                      <div class="ingredient" data-calories="9.2" data-carbs="2.2" data-fat="0" data-proteins="0.1">
                        <p>Chinese Sweet & Sour
                          <p>
                      </div>

                      <td>
                        <div class="ingredient" data-calories="14.6" data-carbs="3" data-fat="0.2" data-proteins="0.2">
                          <p>Coriander
                            <p>
                        </div>

                        <td>
                          <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                            <p>PADTEA FIT
                              <p>
                          </div>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="ingredient" data-calories="506.9" data-carbs="76.9" data-fat="14.1" data-proteins="18.1">
            <p>Vermicelli
              <p>
          </div>

          <td>
            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="50.1" data-carbs="0.4" data-fat="2.9" data-proteins="5.6">
              <p>Smoked Tofu
                <p>
            </div>

            <td>
              <div class="ingredient" data-calories="11.2" data-carbs="2.5" data-fat="0" data-proteins="0.3">
                <p>Sweet Pepper Mix
                  <p>
              </div>

              <td>
                <div class="ingredient" data-calories="15.3" data-carbs="1.4" data-fat="0.9" data-proteins="0.4">
                  <p>Indonesia-Satay
                    <p>
                </div>


                <td>
                  <div class="ingredient" data-calories="95" data-carbs="1.4" data-fat="8.2" data-proteins="3.9">
                    <p>Sesame Seed
                      <p>
                  </div>

                  <td>
                    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                      <p>PADTEA POWER
                        <p>
                    </div>

      </tr>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Please include all valid code *within* the question. Your link to the Codepen is broken, presumably in an attempt to get around the restriction on questions without code.

Comment: You presume incorrectly. I just made a mistake. :) Fixed.

Comment: Your HTML isn't valid - you've got a mish-mash of nested `div`, `p` and `td` elements which is incorrect. I'd suggest fixing that ASAP

Comment: Valid point, although I don't see how this would influence the calculator's functionality at this point.

Comment: It wouldn't, which is why I made it as a comment :) Just letting you know it needs addressing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue caused by the limitations of the internal floating point representation. For instance, the number 0.1 cannot be *exactly* represented in IEEE 754 floating point. So once you start adding up such numbers, the error margin increases, and at some point the conversion of such numbers to a string format (decimal) starts showing these tiny fractions of differences.

Since your base numbers have just one decimal digit, here is how to fix it for your case. Replace all occurrences of this pattern:

```
totalNum.html(currentCalories - calories);
```

with:

```
totalNum.text(+(currentCalories - calories).toFixed(1));
```

Same for additions.

NB: Use `text()` instead of `html()` when what you want to display is text and not HTML.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was it. I guess I need to learn the foundation as well. ^^ Have a great day!